# MySql table and statistics

Tags: mysql, statistics

I am using [Charts.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) to create graphs of user input statistics.

MySql table (simplified) looks like this:

```
student_id| question1
----------------------------
        1 | I like Vanilla
        2 | I like Chocolate
        3 | I like Chocolate
        4 | I like Vanilla
        5 | I like Chocolate
```

What I would like to do is select the column `question1` and start creating statistics for it for each specific answer.
i.e. I would like to know how many `I like Vanilla` and how many `I like Chocolate` answers are there, then I can create a graph where `X` axis displays all the different answers and `Y` axis that displays the number of students that picked that specific answers.

Now, since this illustration is simplified and I don't want to use something like a lot of `if statements` of column equal to some hard-coded string, i'm looking for a more elegant variable-based solution.

Could you please guide me toward creating an elegant solution?

Thanks

Comment: IDs here are comprised of 9 digits... bah, changed it, hope you're happy now.

Comment: Those functions will sum, avg, max, min etc... will be used obviously, what i'm not sure about is how to use variables instead of hard-coded strings. Thanks for being negative by the way.

Comment: @Strawberry seems like there's a much simpler approach. Thanks for the help... NOT

Comment: You have no idea what I tried and didn't try. I never asked anyone for a solution, I asked for **guidance**. English is not my native language so it's not as easy as you think to find things online, what might seem extremely easy to you might be very difficult for me. If you can help, help, if not, please go away..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     SELECT question1,COUNT(student_ID) AS subtotal
     FROM t1 
     GROUP BY question1 
     ORDER BY COUNT(Student_ID) DESC
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, could you explain a bit about this code? how does it get all possible answers?

Comment: @Strawberry hence my request for explanation. Can you please stop trolling this post and help?